# Clarifying a proof of a particular paper on Steins Estimator

Tags: mathematical-statistics, prior, posterior, conditional-expectation, steins-phenomenon

I am trying proving result (5.4) of the [following paper.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177012104)  Its a paper on Steins estimator on spherically symmetric cases.

The doubt is a s follows:

Given 
$$X|\theta\sim \mathcal{N}(\theta,I)$$ with a given two stage prior as $$\theta|\lambda\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}I\right)$$ and $$\lambda\sim (1-b)\lambda^{-b}$$

The authors say that a **straigntforward** calculation reveals that $$E(\theta|X)=[1-E(\lambda|X)]X$$

But this isn't at all straightforward to me. Maybe I am messing up with the conditions and expectations. Can someone help please?